# Building a dictionary in Python value per value, What's the best data structure to achieve this and end up with a list of dicts?

Tags: python, dataframe, defaultdict

I am building a table from an API data, so I need to iterate by the required metrics one by one to get this information. So my output should look something like this:

```
[
{"d1":"dvalue", "d2":"dvalue", "d3":"dvalue",..., "m1":"value", "m2":"value", "m3":"value",...},
{"d1":"dvalue2", "d2":"dvalue2", "d3":"dvalue2",..., "m1":"value2", "m2":"value2", "m3":"value2",...},
...
]
```

But, as said, I need to iterate over mX for all the dX, one by one.

I was thinking in using pandas dataframe, but read about inserting a lot of values from scratch is not the best idea.

So what's on my mind right now, is using a defaultdict of type dict using tuples as keys, so it would look something like this:

```
{
("dvalue", "dvalue", "dvalue",...) : {"m1":"value", "m2":"value", "m3":"value",...},
("dvalue2", "dvalue2", "dvalue2",...) : {"m1":"value2", "m2":"value2", "m3":"value2",...},
...
}
```

So I think that over iterations would be easier to find where to insert the mx value. But I have no clue about how to pass from this structure to the required output.

Thank you in advance, guys!

Comment: If your API outputs, as I imagine, JSON data, why not use pandas to read directly the formatted JSON? Is there a reason why you need to explicitly loop through the response?

Comment: Dictionary `{}` doesn't have an order of items, so if you have a tuple `("dvalue2", "dvalue2", "dvalue2",...)`, there is no way to know to which "m" key each "
dvalue" corresponds

Comment: @AlexeyS.Larionov I think he's mstching them by the numeric suffix: d1=>m1, d2=>m2, etc.

Comment: Also, since python 3.6 dictionaries retain their insertion order.

Comment: @Barmar then if we're talking about performance, it will be too slow anyway

Comment: Please show a sample of the input data.

Comment: @AlexeyS.Larionov , I thought there were an order in tuples so I could make something like `m̀y_struct[(a,b,c)][m3] = "value_m3"` where d1=a, d2=b, d3=c. Hope I explain myself

Comment: @Droid gonna give it a try, but is going to be a lot of "temporal" dataframes...